# What are some accepted patterns to load a UITableView with server-side data?

Tags: ios, database, uitableview, design-patterns, thread-safety

**Goal:** A UITableView(Controller) that:

- Loads server-side content and:
- Feels responsive to the user (e.g. progress wheels)
- Is thread-safe

**My current approach:** My current approach feels very complicated. SO: please help, as there has to be a better way!

1. Declare some required instance variables, for example: (A) an array for sections headings (e.g. "Section 1", "Section 2"), (B) a dictionary to map each section heading to an array of objects that correspond to one row each.

MyTableViewController.m

```
@interface MyTableViewController ()

@property NSArray *sectionHeadings;
@property NSArray *sectionHeadingsTemp;
// Contains (NSString *) objects, such as @"Section 1" and @"Section 2"

@property NSDictionary *sectionsMappedToRowObjects;
@property NSDictionary *sectionsMappedToRowObjectsTemp;
// Contains (NSString *) keys as above and NSArray objects, which contain (MYRow *) objects

@end
```

*(Note. I will explain what the 'Temp' versions are for in due course)*

2. These will underpin the table creation

MyTableViewController.m

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.sectionHeadings count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *section = self.sectionHeadings[indexPath.section];
    NSArray *arrayOfObjects = [self.sectionsMappedToRowObjects objectForKey:section];
    return [arrayOfObjects count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RA_RecommendedMatchCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell_id" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *section = self.sectionHeadings[indexPath.section];
    NSArray *arrayOfObjects = [self.sectionsMappedToRowObjects objectForKey:section];
    MYRow *object = arrayOfObjects[indexPath.row];

    [cell configureCellWith:object]; // Implementation in this file somewhere
    return cell;
}
```

3. Now, the problem is that these instance variables are `nil` when we first load `MyTableViewController`, and they won't be fully ready for some time, because we'll be waiting for database queries to run. In fact, we want to do all that work asynchronously and show the user an MBProgressHUD while it's working.

MyTableViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Prepare the progress HUD
    MBProgressHUD *HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
    HUD.delegate = self;

    // Start the HUD while running prepareTable in the background
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(prepareTable) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}

-(void)prepareTable
{
    // Do time consuming things like run database queries
    ...

    // Ultimately assign all the 'Temp' instance variables
    ...

    // Now go back to the main thread, because it's not thread-safe to stay in the background for this next part
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(completeTableUpdate) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

4. The `completeTableUpdate` moves back to the main thread to assign the non-'Temp' properties and to trigger `reloadData`. I was plagued by nightmare crashes until I did this.

MyTableViewController.m

```
-(void)completeTableUpdate
{
    self.sectionHeadings = [NSArray arrayWithArray:sectionHeadingsTemp];
    self.sectionsMappedToRowObjects = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary self.sectionsMappedToRowObjectsTemp];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: You can cache the data, read the data from cache first, reload tableView after network finished to keep tableView responsive and not empty except for the first time. What do you think about this?

Comment: Would you use Core Data for the cache? (I've yet to get into that)